# Can I pass a variable name in json path expression in jmeter json extractor?

Tags: jmeter

For below json response -
I am extracting all the ids as flight_id in one json extractor.
 Now I want to extract the value of status for all the flight_ids(123, 456) obtained above.

For this I added another json extractor under a For each controller, the json path expression I am using is -

$..data[*].[?(@.[".flights"][?(@.["__id"] == '${flight_id}')])].[".status"]

But this doesnt seem to be working, I cant see status being returned in debug sampler.
Can I not pass variable name in the json path expression ?

Is there any other way of doing this ?
Thanks!

```
{
"count": 1,
"data": [
    {
        "__id": "ed6f709c-fc38-4b0e-9064-1170b1a0403d",
        "__r": 43,
        "__mb": "674a2597-07cb-46a2-a32c-e9bda1171b6d",
        "__m": "2018-01-24T21:27:03.689-05:00",
        ".auths": [],
        ".createdBy": "7f281748-16de-4f65-901c-61f1a0f2fed4",
        ".createdDate": "2017-12-04T21:45:37.592-05:00",
        ".currency": "VND",
        ".events": [],
        ".factsheets": [],
        ".flights": 
        [
            {
            "__id": "123",
            "__r": 43,
            "__mb": "7f281748-16de-4f65-901c-61f1a0f2fed4",
            "__m": "2017-12-11T09:18:09.755-05:00",
            ".latestAuthorization": null,
            ".latestAuthorizationStatus": null,
            ".status": "budgeted",
            ".subflights": [

            ],
            "addedValue.actual": null,
            "addedValue.booked": null,

          },
          {
            "__id": "456",
            "__r": 43,
            "__mb": "7f281748-16de-4f65-901c-61f1a0f2fed4",
            "__m": "2017-12-11T09:18:09.755-05:00",
            ".latestAuthorization": null,
            ".latestAuthorizationStatus": null,
            ".status": "actual",
            ".subflights": [

            ],
            "addedValue.actual": null,
            "addedValue.booked": null,

          }
        ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Given you provided:

1. Only a partial JSON
2. The JSON is malformed (it is missing comma between flights)

It is quite hard to say what's wrong, however given correct JSON Payload like:

```
[
  {
    "__id": "123",
    "__r": 43,
    "__mb": "7f281748-16de-4f65-901c-61f1a0f2fed4",
    "__m": "2017-12-11T09:18:09.755-05:00",
    ".latestAuthorization": null,
    ".latestAuthorizationStatus": null,
    ".status": "budgeted",
    ".subflights": [

    ],
    "addedValue.actual": null,
    "addedValue.booked": null,

  },
  {
    "__id": "456",
    "__r": 43,
    "__mb": "7f281748-16de-4f65-901c-61f1a0f2fed4",
    "__m": "2017-12-11T09:18:09.755-05:00",
    ".latestAuthorization": null,
    ".latestAuthorizationStatus": null,
    ".status": "actual",
    ".subflights": [

    ],
    "addedValue.actual": null,
    "addedValue.booked": null,

  }
]
```

And the following JSON Path query:

```
$..[?(@.__id == '${flight_id}')].[".status"]
```

It works fine and returns either `budgeted` for `123` or `actual` for `456`

You can validate your JSON Path query using `JSON Path Tester` mode of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener. See [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more details if needed.

[image: JMeter View Results Tree validate JSON]

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri. 
I have updated the json format in my question & I am using this json path query to get the value of status but, I am not getting anything back. 
`$..data[*].[".flights"][*].[?(@.__id == '${flight_id}')].[".status"]`